# Insertion sort C code not working correctly, it only sorts top two elements

Tags: c, algorithm, insertion-sort

I am not able to figure out the mistake in this code, this code is error free but it doesn't give correct results.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{

    int a[10], n, i, j, k, value_to_insert, hole_pos;
    printf("Enter the total no: of elements in an array");
    scanf("%d", &n);


    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    }

    for (j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
        value_to_insert=a[j];
        hole_pos=j;

        while (j > 0 && value_to_insert < a[hole_pos - 1]) {
            a[hole_pos]=a[hole_pos-1];
            hole_pos=hole_pos-1;
        }

        a[hole_pos] = value_to_insert;
    }

    printf("Sorted Array \n");
    for (k = 0; k < n; k++)
        printf("%d\n", a[k]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's not written in Xcode, it's written in C.

Comment: There are lots of problems with this code. 1. The loop index goes up to n which is one past the valid range of the array, the while loop increments nothing and will therefore never terminate.

Comment: i am using xcode to compile this program.

Comment: please help c.fogelklou, i would really appreciate.

Comment: Sorry baby crying can't finish checking but here is what I tried to change my first comment to: a[n] is beyond the valid range for the array, and you get there via j<=n. You terminate the while loop checking j>0 but are decrementing hole_pos.

Comment: Your algorithm and its implementation are on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort)

Comment: Why don't you run your program in a debugger?

Comment: @ring0 I know. Now what?

Comment: The code is error-free but it doesn't give the correct results? Isn't that a contradiction?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the loop condition `j <= n` there should be `j < n`

Instead of `j > 0` there should be `hole_pos > 0`

If you write code, you should know how and what it does. Why would you write `j > 0` in that while loop, when `j` wasn't even getting decremented in the loop?

Answer (score 0):

There is a error in the line 
`for (j = 1; j <= n; j++)
value_to_insert=a[j];` 
When the value of j is equal to n you are crossing the boundary of the array. 
so it should be
`for (j = 1; j < n; j++)value_to_insert=a[j];`

Another error is in the line 
`while (j > 0 && value_to_insert < a[hole_pos - 1])`

Here the condition `j>0` is always true because j starts from 1. 
This line should be written as

`while (hole_pos > 0 && value_to_insert < a[hole_pos - 1])`.

Each time you decrement `hole_pos` you should check it before you enter loop. Hope this helps.